# get associated records in ms dynamics crm

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Hi to get associated records from campaignlist_association in ms crm 2013. Tried tons of different variations.

This is last one:

```
System.Guid campaignId = ((EntityReference)entity.Attributes["regardingobjectid"]).Id;


var list = (from c in EntityCon.CampaignSet
            join l in EntityCon.ListSet on c.campaignlist_association equals l.campaignlist_association
            where c.CampaignId == campaignId select c).First();
```

Comment: what error do you get? is it that your queries don't get any results?

Comment: Error 57 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Comment: well that's your answer then

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

indicates that the types of the properties used with the equals expression must match, e.g. that they are both `Int32` or `Guid`.

Make sure that the type `l.campaignlist_association` is the same as the type `c.campaignlist_association`.

Comment: No. I don't think this is a problem. Problem is I don.t get it how to get data out from campaignlist_association. Basicly, this is N:N relation without available table with both Id's.

Answer (score 0):

I would use code as follows to get the associated entity records. Change the column set as per your requirement.

```
private EntityCollection GetAssociatedEntityItems(string relationshipName, string relatedEntityName, string entityName, Guid entityId)
    {
        EntityCollection result = null;
            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
            query.EntityName = relatedEntityName;
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false);
            Relationship relationship = new Relationship();
            relationship.SchemaName = relationshipName;
            relationship.PrimaryEntityRole = EntityRole.Referencing;
            RelationshipQueryCollection relatedEntity = new RelationshipQueryCollection();
            relatedEntity.Add(relationship, query);
            RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
            request.RelatedEntitiesQuery = relatedEntity;
            request.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

            request.Target = new EntityReference
            {
                Id = entityId,
                LogicalName = entityName
            };
            RetrieveResponse response = (RetrieveResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(request);
            RelatedEntityCollection relatedEntityCollection = response.Entity.RelatedEntities;
            if (relatedEntityCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                if (relatedEntityCollection.Values.Count > 0)
                {
                    result = (EntityCollection)relatedEntityCollection.Values.ElementAt(0);
                }
            }
        return result;
    }
```